# Using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a batch file that can connect to the remote server without an issue. I now want it to read the sql script that works fine thru the gui and export the data to csv.  The two pieces work perfectly together but I am getting the error argument ignored. I have tried -f, -i but there most be something I am missing.

Here is what is in my file. I have also tried with -f as well. Any help would be appreciated. (This is a windows machine)

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "c:\program files\postgresql\15\bin"
psql "host=servername port=5432 dbname=dayforce user=user password=password" 
\i okta.sql
```

I am running this script

```
copy (select e.contacts->>'BusinessEmail' as username, 
split_part(e.display_name, ', ', 2) as firstname, split_part(e.display_name, ', ',1) as lastname TO
'/okta/oktaincremental/test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER
```

Comment: The script I am trying to run is as follows:

Comment: \copy (select e.contacts->>'BusinessEmail' as username, split_part(e.display_name, ', ', 2) as firstname, split_part(e.display_name, ', ',1)  as lastname
TO '/okta/oktaincremental/test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to execute an SQL script through the command line with psql is:

```
psql "host=servername port=etc..." -f okta.psql
```

The metacommand `\i okta.sql` is to be used inside psql or inside an SQL script, it cannot be used on the command line itself as an argument to psql.

Comment: I went ahead a did that, still the same error. Nothing in the log files. Not sure what to do from here.